# Change the width of the plot

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart

I create a bar plot with python :

```
df['market_sub_segment'].value_counts().plot.bar(title="Freq dist of sub_market_segment")
```

My question is how to make the plot bigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use figsize:

```
df.plot(figsize=(15,2));
```

From the docs:
"figsize : a tuple (width, height) in inches"